# EF6 How to iterate child Collections of a Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, collections, t4

I have several Entity classes (I am using EF6 database first), that may contains 0, 1 or more child table collections.

This is an example:

```
public partial class MyEntity : DBRow
{
    public MyEntity ()
    {
        this.Child1 = new HashSet<Child1>();
        this.Child2 = new HashSet<Child2>();
    }

    public string COl1{ get; set; }
    public string COl2 { get; set; }
    public string COl3 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child1> Childs1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child2> Childs2 { get; set; }
}
```

There is a way to iterate in a generic way by index, enumerator, or whatever?

I am looking to do something like:

```
foreach(var colection in MyEntity.Collections
{
//do somelogic
}
```

If this cannot be done easy, I believe that I may need to modify the T4 template. I am very newbie with T4 templates; so, any hint on what I should search would be very appreciated.

Any idea is welcome! Thanks!

Comment: What would the type of `colection` be? What do you need to do for each collection?

Comment: If all the collections are of the same (base) type, you can introduce a collection property that `Concat()`enates them, but that might not result in the best query plan.